# Getting ''operands could not be broadcast together with shapes'' Error in Manim

Tags: python, manim

I am getting a broadcast error while transforming Two `MathTex` objects  `Transform(p_q_value, sqr_rt)`, in **Manim**. If i comment the `p_q_value.add_updater` line its works fine(not updated value, previous value), why its giving a broadcast error after adding update.

**Code:**

```
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tracker = ValueTracker(0)
        p_q_value = MathTex(
            r"0", r"\;=\;", r"{0", r"\over", r"1}").move_to(ORIGIN)
        self.play(Write(p_q_value))

        p_q_value.add_updater(lambda mobj: mobj.become(MathTex(
            f"{tracker.get_value():.0f}", r"\;=\;", fr"{{{tracker.get_value():.0f}\over", r"1}").move_to(ORIGIN)))
        self.play(tracker.animate.set_value(10), run_time=5)

        sqr_rt = MathTex(r"\sqrt{16}")

        self.play(ReplacementTransform(p_q_value, sqr_rt))
        self.wait(4)
```

**Error:**

> │    47 │   │   sqr_rt = MathTex(r"\sqrt{16}")
> │    48 │   │
> │ ❱  49 │   │   self.play(ReplacementTransform(p_q_value, sqr_rt))
> │    50 │   │   self.wait(4)
> │    51 │   │
> │    52 │   │
> ##############################################################
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (48,3) (76,3)  [35895] Execution returned code=1 in 1.405 seconds
> returned signal null

**############### Update ###############**

Solved the issue by turning off the updater function before the transition.

```
sqr_rt = MathTex(r"\sqrt{16}")
p_q_value.clear_updaters() # <<<< add this line before transition 
self.play(Transform(p_q_value, sqr_rt))
self.wait(4)
```

Answered by @[uwezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8125472/uwezi?tab=profile) on discord https://discord.com/channels/581738731934056449/1042651621152272434